# How to test Flutter app made from Android Studio on iPhone

Tags: android-studio, flutter

As you can tell from the question I'm a newbie to Flutter world.  I just finished making a simple Flutter app using Android Studio IDE, and would like to test on my iPhone.  Is there a way to do this from within Android Studio?  If not, do I just use Xcode?  Any detailed instruction would be appreciated!!

Comment: What troubles have you had launching the iPhone app on your mac?  Does "flutter devices" show your iphone?

Comment: Wasn't showing up because I did not connect my iPhone to Mac.  Didn't know it was as simple as that!  :). thx

Comment: Is this where I use the LOL emoji? :)

Comment: it is..  but now I am getting an error that says "The certificate used to sign "Runner" has either expired or has been revoked. An updated certificate is required to sign and install the application."  I keep trying...  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find how to run an app from Android Studio in [Official Flutter Documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/android-studio). Also, for run and test your iOS app, you need Mac computer.

Comment: Geez, I didn't know it was as simple as connecting my iPhone to my Mac.  It still doesn't install and run on my iPhone because of some certificate issue but at least I know how to  test on a real device!  thx